# Checkin values inside an array inside session array HMVC Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

i am making this one where i want to pass the user data on my sessions as you can see on my codes

controller

```
public function loginValidate(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('USERNAME','Username','required|trim|callback_validateCreds');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('PASSWORD','Password','required|trim');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){

        $this->index();

    }else{
        $data = array(
            'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
            'is_logged_in' => true,
--------->>'user_data' => $this->Login_Model->userinfo()
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        $this->dashboard();
    }
}
```

models

```
public function userinfo(){

    $sql = "SELECT
                tbl_users.ID_NUM,
                tbl_users.USERNAME,
                user_group.GROUP_NAME,
                user_rights.RIGHTS,
                usertypes.USERTYPE,
                department.DEPARTMENT
            FROM tbl_users
                INNER JOIN user_group
                ON tbl_users.GROUP_ID = user_group.GROUP_ID
                INNER JOIN user_rights
                ON user_group.GROUP_ID = user_rights.GROUP_ID
                INNER JOIN usertypes
                ON user_rights.RIGHTS = usertypes.USERCODE
                INNER JOIN department
                ON usertypes.DEP_ID = department.DEP_ID
            WHERE tbl_users.USERNAME = ?
            AND tbl_users.PASSWORD = ? ";

    $data = array(
                    'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
                    'PASSWORD' => $this->input->post('PASSWORD')
                );

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data);
    return $query;
}
```

what i wanted to do is when i log-in to check the values inside my user_data array. for example

```
if (userdata array in my sessions array have the value admin){

show this}
```

i cannot or atleast i dont think that i can break down that array because my query output will be for example.

```
---------------------------------------------
username   |  group_name     |  rights     |
---------------------------------------------
abc        |  group_1        |  admin1     |
---------------------------------------------
abc        |  group_1        |  admin2     |
---------------------------------------------
abc        |  group_1        |  admin3     |
---------------------------------------------
```

how will i be able to check that array inside the sessions array if some specific value is inside that array. for example if the array has admin1 i'll do this and etc..

Comment: use this code '$this->session->userdata['USERNAME']' or if($this->session->userdata['USERNAME']=='admin')

Comment: okay. i'll try it.

Comment: : Undefined index: DEPARTMENT is what i get.

Comment: '$sessionarray = $this->session->userdata()' and print_r($sessionarray)

Comment: its too long to post here

Comment: can you open a chat for us?

Comment: Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1458624179 [USERNAME] => admin [is_logged_in] => 1 [user_data] => CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 3 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $

Comment: [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 6 [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.6.24 [server_version] => 50624 [stat] => Uptime: 10935 Threads: 1 Questions: 21962 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 103 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 96 Queries per second avg: 2.008 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10

Comment: [thread_id] => 2425 [warning_count] => 0 ) [result_id] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 6 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 3 [type] => 0 ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => [row_data] => ) )

Comment: now your can use if( $sessionarray['USERNAME'] == 'admin')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106973/discussion-between-aslam-patel-and-kev-m).

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$sessionarray = $this->session->userdata();

$sessionarray['USERNAME'] ;
```

or your condition

```
if($sessionarray['USERNAME']=='admin')
```

Comment: bec i have `$data = array(
--------->> 'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
            'is_logged_in' => true,
'user_data' => $this->Login_Model->userinfo()
        );` but when i tried to do `$sessionarray['DEPARTMENT'] ;` on which the department is on userdata() it had an error of undefined index

Comment: in you session not department so not get department first you put department in session.